# How to remove a smokey/ charcoal taste from food?

Tags: flavor

I just cooked a huge batch of burrito filling.  Everything seemed okay, but then it turned out to have a really disgusting charcoal aftertaste.  I think maybe some burned bits got stirred in while I was cooking it.  Can you tell me how to remove the taste? I find it inedible, but it's about $50 dollars of ingredients.  Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If you catch it before you've stirred it in, you can sometimes scoop out all but the stuff at the bottom of the pan into a new pan, but once it's mixed in, I don't know of any way to mask it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I don't think there is anything you can do to remove that flavor. It sounds like what is often described as "scorched" flavor. In restaurants, that is well known as the one flavor you can't mask, you just have to dump the whole batch and move on. You can feel free to take a shot at masking it with acid (lemon, vinegar, ...), salt, sugar, and spices, but I don't think it is going to work.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me last summer when on vacation and I was making a large pot of sauce in a really lousy pan on the vacation rental. It was thin metal, on on an electric stove, and quickly burned the tomato sauce to the bottom of the pan.

We transferred it to a new pan, but it was too late.

Lots of advice online about mixing in peanut butter or whole peeled potatoes as solutions that will not affect the flavor of the tomato sauce.

We tried both. Neither made a difference.